# HOA enforcement of rules

Tags: hoa

Neighbor put up trampoline and planted fruit trees. HOA gave them violation notices as they are not allowed in our community. Neighbor put trampoline and trees (now in 5 gallon pots) onto their paved patio, which is covered but not screened in. HOA claims they cannot take any more action. Is this true or would the HOA attorney be able to intervene.

Comment: It sounds like something that depends on the wording of your HOA contract.

Comment: Notice that the two cases involve "put up" and "put on patio". Look in the contract to see what difference there is.

Comment: How do they use a trampoline under a roof?  Do they wear helmets?